# Dynamic style change in tabhost

Tags: java, android, styles

Sorry for my awful English.
There is an application in android `TabHost`. Tabs include `Activity`.
In the application I use the menu compile from `prefs.xml`

How can I  change dynamic font size in activity only??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can alter text size using this:

```
int size = 12;
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
textView.setTextSize(size);
```